# How to track if data has been loaded in fully reactive way?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Consider following code

```js
 heroes: Obserable<Hero[]>;
 private _loadHeroes: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmmiter;

 constructor(heroService: HeroService) {
    this.heroes = _loadHeroes.switchMap(() => heroService.fetchHeroes());
 }
```

Does anyone have any clue how without doing manual subscription to add something like `heroesLoaded: BehaviorSubject<boolean>` in a proper reactive way?
Sure I could do something like

```js
    this.heroes = _loadHeroes.switchMap(() => {
      this.heroesLoaded.next(false)
      heroService.fetchHeroes().finally(() => this.heroesLoaded.next(true)
    });
```

But I believe this not the best way of doing it, the idea is to leave all subscriptions to async pipe and do everything only in streams. Also I don't want to write it using impure side effects as described above. I tried looking towards pulishBehavior operator, but I don't see how I can use it to react to both moment of subscription and moment of value emmitting/error. Is it possible at all? I am interested in any possible solution that would be at least better, not necessarily perfect.

Comment: By calling `this.heroesLoaded.next` you're not creating new subscriptions if this is what you worry about.

Comment: I know that I don't, but it's not really right approach, is it? we shouldn't do side effects inside map function

Comment: Side effects in `*map` operators are indeed not a good idea, but you can use the `tap` or `finalize` operators for these things (if you use this approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to keep track of whether they are loaded (e.g. to show a loading indicator):

```
heroes: Obserable<Hero[]>;
heroesLoaded: boolean = false;

constructor(heroService: HeroService) {
   this.heroesLoaded = false;
   this.heroes = of(null).pipe(
       tap(() => this.heroesLoaded = false),
       flatMap(() => heroService.fetchHeroes()),
       finalize(() => this.heroesLoaded = true)
   );
}
```

You could make heroesLoaded an BehaviorSubject if you want and replace the line `this.heroesLoaded = false` with `this.heroesLoaded.next(false)` - I don't see what advantages that would bring but the principle of using tap and finalize would be the same.

Comment: that I know, but in my example I don't use directly observable of http request, but it's another observable, in that case side effects with tap, finilize would be inside switchMap, or that's ok?

Comment: @BlindDespair No, it's ok for them to be at the top level like in the example I show. Either will work but there's no need to nest them.

Comment: I was aware of this way of doing it, just hoped that there is better approach

Comment: Another approach could be simply to start the observable with `of(null)` then `concatMap` to `heroService.fetchHeroes()`. This would cause the output from the overall chain to be first null then the loaded data, which you could react to in your template (e.g. `<div *ngIf="heroes | async as heroes; else loading">` then have a #loading template) @BlindDespair

Comment: that was also one of my ideas @Mark Hughes, but it would require me to update all my typings in every place to be updated to `heroes: Observable<Hero[] | null>` and then do a null check in every place I use it, so each of the solution has its pros and cons

Comment: @BlindDespair null is a valid value for type `Hero[]` so I would not thing you would need to change the type. You are correct though that you'd need to do the null check.

Comment: @BlindDespair ... of course, you could also do a .pipe(filter((a) => a != null)) to get a version of the observable that didn't emit the null in places where you didn't care about the "loading" state.